# SSIS package .csv to .xlsx need to overwrite

Tags: excel, csv, ssis

I have an SSIS package that converts a .csv file into an .xlsx file before being loaded into SQL. Is there a way to have a process that overwrites the current .xlsx file instead of adding data into the .xlsx that currently exists?

Thx in advance.

Comment: anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS package .csv to .xlsx need to overwrite instead of adding data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180563/ssis-package-csv-to-xlsx-need-to-overwrite-instead-of-adding-data)