# SSIS package .csv to .xlsx need to overwrite instead of adding data

Tags: excel, csv, ssis, flat-file

I have an SSIS package that converts a .csv file into an .xlsx file before being loaded into SQL. Is there a way to have a process that overwrites the current .xlsx file instead of adding data into the .xlsx that currently exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overwriting excel destination in SSIS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018502/how-to-overwriting-excel-destination-in-ssis)

Comment: @MattGibson yes, thank you. This was exactly what I needed.